# Are any present particles entangled due to their common origin in the big bang?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-entanglement, big-bang

Are any present particles entangled due to their common origin in the beg bang? Have they been too transformed to be entangled or never entangled to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Take any two particles A and B that have interacted with each other, and they are for all practical purposes forever entangled.  If particle C then interacts with B, C is thereafter entangled with both B and A, and so on and on.  The entanglement with a particle Z gets more and more diluted as the number of interactions with other particles increases between the original pair and Z, but the overall entanglement remains.

To prevent all particles from being mutually entangled throughout the universe, the universe would have had to expand so fast in the big bang that light - or gravitational waves- could never reach from each of the original particles or fields to all the others, in the time span of the universe's existence.  To *detect or measure* that entanglement, though, might well be impossible.

In lab experiments, we can cause two particles to interact and then prevent them from interacting with other particles, long enough to detect and measure the *new* entanglement between them due to the interaction we caused.